# General Subspace proof

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ and $V$ be any subspaces of a vector space $W$. Show that $U \cap V$ is a subspace of $W$.

Proof. We must show that $U\cap V$ is non-empty, closed under + and closed under scalar *.

1. Since $U$ and $V$ are subspaces $0 \in U \land 0 \in V \implies 0 \in U \cap V$
2. Let $x$ and $y$ be any elements of $U \cap V$

consider $x+y$: (**I need help here**)

1. Let $x$ be any element in $U \cap V$ and let $a$ be any field element

consider $a\cdot x$ (**I need help here**)

I drew a venn-diagram and this property does not seem intuitive at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part, note that $x\in U$ and $y\in U$; as $U$ is a subspace of $W$, $x+y\in U$. By the same argument, $x+y\in V$, as $V$ is a subspace of $W$.

Do the same for $a\cdot x$.

We notice that we can generalize it to an arbitrary intersection of subspaces (not necessarily a finite one).